# In gradle is it possible to discover which artifacts in a given maven repository depend on any version of a given "group:module"?

Tags: gradle, gitlab

We have a private maven repository where we are publishing artifacts (using gradle).

When we create a new version of an artifact, say "mygroup:mymodule", I want to find out which other artifacts in our repository depend on any version of "mygroup:mymodule", so that we can check and see if they need upgrading to the newly published version.

Is there a way to determine this list of artifacts that depend on a known artifact in gradle?

In case it matters, the maven repository we are using is [GitLab's "group level Maven endpoint"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/maven_repository.html#group-level-maven-endpoint). Our artifacts are spread across multiple GitLab projects in our GitLab group. We want to query the group's maven endpoint so that we can discover artifacts in other projects that depend on artifacts in the current project.

Note that I am *not* asking for the set of artifacts that the given artifact depends on, but rather the set of artifacts that depend on the given artifact (regardless of version).

Comment: Gradle gets artifacts by GAV (group, artifact, version) from the repository. It can't query the repository like this. Please tell us which repository you are using (eg nexus or artifactory) and perhaps the repository has a query API you can call

Comment: Eg https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api

Comment: @lance-java I am using [GitLab's maven repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/maven_repository.html). It's the "group level" maven repository I need to query.